Use the mouse wheel on the desktop to switch workspaces
I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with LXQT und I want use the mouse wheel anywhere over the desktop to switch workspaces. I found the setting in /usr/bin/xfwm4-tweaks-settings and it was already activated. However, it doesn't work - it simply does nothing. I've used this feature in the previous version and everything was fine.
Using the mouse wheel over the workplace switcher in the task bar works as expected.
Any ideas on how to debug/resolve this issue?

You mention xfwm4 which is the Xfce WM, and also mention Lubuntu (in tags) and LXQt, where Lubuntu defaults to using the openbox WM, so changing settings in a different WM to the default would be expected to do nothing... Have you switched your system to use xfwm4 since you've made configuration changes there?

Sorry, my mistake. It's not lubuntu. I kind of thought it was, because of the l in lxqt, but that was wrong. ps faux shows lxqt-session and /usr/bin/xwm4 running...
